# Can I free a linked list without passing reference to the head?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to free my whole linked list with the function below. However, since I am passing a copy of `head` to the function, at the end `head` doesn't point to `NULL`, but to something else. Because of this my program crashes. Can somebody explain to me where `head` actually points to and is there a way to change it to `NULL` without passing a double pointer?

```
void free_list(Node *head) {
    Node *curr_item = head;

    if(head == NULL) {
        printf("\nLinked list is empty\n\n");
        menu();
    }

    while(head != NULL) {
        curr_item = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(curr_item);
    }

    menu();
}
```

Comment: Define your function as `Node **phead` so that you can assign `*phead = NULL`.

Comment: You can use return value to tell the caller what should be the new value of head. (calling `menu()` from this function looks weird and there seems some problems in your design)

Comment: You can change head to NULL by writing `head = NULL;`, but since you want the other function's head variable to be NULL, you have to write it in that function.

Comment: I did it by passing a reference to head, as @iBug suggested. I was just curious if there was other way around. @MikeCAT the purpose of the program is to add/delete nodes to/from linked list at any time. I am calling `menu()` so the user can go back and choose to continue with the program or exit.

Comment: The caller of `free_list(head)` could just set `head = NULL;` after the call. (I don't know what `menu();` does, but it probably doesn't belong in this function. Also, the function calls `menu();` twice if the list is empty.)

Comment: @IanAbbott If the list is empty, the first `if` will catch it and `menu()` will be called once? I don't see a case where it is called twice?

Comment: Let's see the code that calls this code. The best place to fix it is probably there. Look at how `free` works and follow that pattern. (Why does `free_list` call `menu`? There's probably something *very* wrong with the calling code. A function called `free_list` should *only* free a list.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can't paste the whole code here, because it is almost 200 lines. I briefly said what the code does in the comments above.  Since it s a menu and you have an option to free the list, I made this if statements if this option is pressed by accident. It is part of a university assignment and the professor often checks if something can break. It might be a bad design pattern, but I don't know how I could have made it better.

Comment: The function does not return immediately after the `menu();` call within the `if`, so it will reach the second `menu();` call at the end of the function. So yes, it is called twice (unless `menu()` never returns).

Comment: @IanAbbott Right. It continues from the point where it stopped. I probably shouldn't allow calling it while `head = NULL`, but I don't think that is possible in the way I coded it.

Comment: You desperately need to learn the [single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). A function that frees a list should not produce a menu. The problem you have is that the code that calls this function needs to do something after freeing the list (set `head` to `NULL`). But it cannot do so because this function does not return after freeing the list. A function that frees a list should just free a list. If something else needs to be done after freeing a list, some other function should do it after calling this one to free the list.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I got your point, thank you. I guess I must now allow going into the function if `head = NULL` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also mentioned in comments: if you don't want to pass a reference to the head pointer, then make the function return the new value of `head` (which will be `NULL`) and have a "contract" that the caller must take the return value as the new value for `head`. You can use this pattern also with other, list-modifying functions, like where you would only delete *one* node (maybe determined by a given value or position), or would insert a new node, ...etc.

Proposed code:

```
Node * free_list(Node *head) {
    Node *curr_item;

    while (head != NULL) {
        curr_item = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(curr_item);
    }

    return head; // is NULL
}
```

The calling code could look like this:

```
    //...
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("\nLinked list is empty\n\n");
    }
    head = free_list(head);
    menu();
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did it by passing a reference to the head pointer, but I think I can implement this pattern for other functions.